# Почему просматривать голоса за/против можно только после 1к реп.?

Tags: обсуждение, репутация, привилегии

Никогда до этого раньше не задумывался, но почему только перейдя порог 1к реп. можно смотреть полную [детальную] оценку того или иного сообщения? Почему не за "бесплатно"; почему именно после 1к? На некоторых сервисах, например, видеохостинг «[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/)», возможность просмотра полной оценки доступна сразу.

Такая же канитель с «Голосовать за», «Отметить тревогой», «Общение в чатах», «Комментировать повсеместно», «Создавать чаты», «Голосовать против», «Видеть голоса за закрытие», «Создавать чаты-витрины». Почему я не могу создать простой чат, не набрав 100 реп.? Почему я могу оставлять комментарий только с 50 реп.? Зачем нужны такие ограничения?

Comment: А их можно смотреть?)

Comment: @eri ну, как бы, да!)

Comment: @eri нажмите на число между стрелками голосования за/против у сообщения

Comment: @αλεχολυτ это как бы шутка была)

Comment: Это я видел, както нажал случайно. Но по вопросу подумал что можно посмотреть кто именно голосовал.

Comment: @eri Кто именно голосовал нельзя, т. к. это неисчерпаемый источник кибербулинга. Посмотрел, кто минус поставил, и сказал ему, чтобы убрал, или <что-то страшное>. А неисчерпаемый, т. к. новых пользователей всё больше и больше, т. е. новых кибербулей всё больше и больше.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Просмотр результатов голосования

Этот вопрос задавался на Meta.SE два раза.

В [Why do vote-counts require 1,000 reputation to see?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37116/why-do-vote-counts-require-1-000-reputation-to-see) один из создателей сайта Jeff Atwood ответил:

> We just thought it would be fun to give folks something at 1000 rep, since there was a bit of a gap between 500 (retag) and 2000 (edit other people's posts).
> *Мы просто подумали, что было бы неплохо дать людям что-нибудь на 1000 репы, т.к. оставался большой промежуток между 500 (изменение меток) и 2000 (правка чужих постов)*

В [Why is it a privilege to view vote counts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69852/why-is-it-a-privilege-to-view-vote-counts) удаленный пользователь дал следующую мотивацию:

> This is because it's ["expensive" to view the vote count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/1007#1007) (in terms of running the query). The rep threshold limits the number of people requesting this data.
> *Потому что с точки зрения выполнения запроса, расчет количества голосов является более ресурсоемкой задачей. Порог репутации ограничивает количество таких запросов*

Мотивация в обоих случаях довольно спорная, но по крайней мере становится ясно что думали разработчики.

Это тот случай когда привилегия интересная, но практической пользы от нее мало. Участник вполне может обойтись без просмотра плюсов и минусов. Поэтому ее и использовали для такого ничего не значащего подарка на 1К.

Величину порога можно оспорить, но, чтобы спор имел смысл, нужно объяснить зачем новичкам право

### Остальные привилегии

Можно выделить два фактора которые в свое время повлияли на успех Stack Overflow и сети Stack Exchange в целом:

1. У сайта очень хорошо получается завлекать пользователей и заставлять их работать за виртуальные очки.
   Репутация, т.о. является частью механики сайта. Она создает игровой элемент, который мотивирует людей часами отвечать на вопросы.
2. Stack Overflow сильно экономит на модераторах. Почти всю работу выполняют пользователи совершенно бесплатно.
   Механика модерации на сайте тоже основана на игровой системе. Пользователи и модераторы-добровольцы готовы часами разбирать очереди проверки ради знаков (еще один игровой элемент) и признания сообщества (без комментариев).

Привилегии хорошо вписываются в эту систему, в общем случае они выполняют несколько задач, например:

- Мотивируют людей зарабатывать виртуальные очки на сайте.
  Пользователь вместе с первыми баллами репутации получает новые возможности в «игре».
- Снижают нагрузку на модераторов.
  Выше я уже упомянул, что львиную долю модераторской работы выполняют добровольцы. Сайту выгодно оградить их от скучной рутины. Чем меньше людей имеют доступ к функции тем меньше людей используют ее для нарушения правил.
- Постепенно обучают пользователей работе с сайтом.
  Если новички будут получать несколько разных способов коммуникации (вопросы/ответы/голоса/комментарии/чат), то будет сложно сразу объяснить им смысл этих инструментов и связанные с ними правила сайта.
  Проще давать возможности по одной пока они набирают репутацию, давать привыкнуть к сайту, попутно объяснять правила.

### Риски

С перечисленными привилегиями связаны определенные риски повышения нагрузки на модераторов:

- любая возможность публикации (чаты/комментарии/тревоги) на сайте может быть использован для спама, либо для нарушения правил;
- «голосование за» может быть использовано для накрутки репутации;
- «голосование против» и «тревоги» для мести и троллинга.

Соответственно, ограничение доступа к этим возможностям снижает нагрузку на модераторов.

Разумеется, это не абсолютный аргумент: вред от расширения возможностей пользователей сложно оценить и, даже если он существенный, SO может принять контрмеры (улучшить фильтры, ужесточить наказания, нанять модераторов).

Но само существование риска накладывает определенные условия на требования расширить доступ новичков к функциям сайта.

### Как оспорить тот или иной порог?

Если Вы хотите снизить порог для той или иной привилегии, то лучше подробно рассказать зачем пользователям ниже порога жизненно необходим доступ к тем или иным функциям. Желательно указать конкретные ситуации, в которых требуется привилегия.

На Meta.SE есть примеры популярных предложений по отдельным привилегиям:

- [Suggested Privilege: Inviting new users to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277652/suggested-privilege-inviting-new-users-to-chat) — дать возможность участникам приглашать новых пользователей в чат.
  В вопросе даются аргументы в пользу изменения: дать возможность живого общения с новичками по необходимости.
- [Allow new users to flag comments on their own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311459/allow-new-users-to-flag-comments-on-their-own-posts) — разрешить новичкам ставить тревоги на комментариях к своим постам.
  В вопросе подробно описаны сценарии в которых это может понадобится. Это изменение уже было реализовано в 2018 году.

Для того чтобы дать дельное предложение по изменению механики сайта или снижению порога нужно сконцентрироваться на какой-то одной привилегии и подробно разобрать кому и для чего она нужна. Обосновать что польза от расширения доступа перевешивает риски, связанные с нарушениями правил.

Любые предложения по механике сайта лучше давать на [главной мете сети](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Ну и окончательное решение будут принимать не пользователи с модераторами, а администрация с разработчиками (<sub>шепотом: скорее всего никто ничего делать не будет</sub>).

Comment: Если человек может посмотреть статистику по голосам за и против - это открывает целый полигон для деструктивных действий

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич Эта часть относится к списку привилегий из второго абзаца в вопросе.

Comment: Всё равно оч. спорная мотивация, ведь на том же ютубе всё сразу доступно. И почему "голос за/против" или "создание чата" – это *деструктивные* действия? Что в этом деструктивного?

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич ??? Я, конечно, понимаю, что это шутка, но тогда давайте запретим VK, или телегу, или Facebook, или любой др. мессенджер, ведь там можно пропагандировать гомосексуализм (я что-то сомневаюсь, что гетеро захочет становиться гомо после пары матов в свой адрес).

Comment: @return Мотивация уж какая есть, за что купил за то и продаю. «Голос за» открывает возможность для накручивания репутации, «голос против» для заминусовывания, «создание чата» для спама. Речь не о том что чаты создавать плохо, а о том, что если миллиону людей дать к ним доступ, то количество нарушений увеличится.

Comment: Телеграм уже запрещали. Вы думаете, что пакет Яровой просто так появился? Там тоже не дураки сидят

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич Глядя на Ваши комменты думается что порог на комментирование все-таки низковат :-)

Comment: @defaultlocale согласен) (только что хотел это написать :) )

Comment: Как быстро вопрос себя исчерпал

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич Вы про какой вопрос? Он ничего не исчерпал: как можно вообще накручивать репу? Антимеры для накрутки принять никак? Или спам в чате: даже в дискорде есть боты для антиспама (причём эти боты довольно просты, но их функционала вполне хватает).

Comment: Вы правы! Мы здесь «ишачим» как рабы за безплатно! : -) Но по сути деньги являются ничем иным как медальками и очками – точно как у этой страницы. За деньги вообще некоторые не то что «ишачить», а и убивать готовы. Вот в таком обществе мы живём и никто не сопротивляется! o_O

Comment: @Bharatha можно и так сказать, но деньги по крайней мере можно обменять на что-нибудь материальное, в отличное от репутации :-)

Answer (score 5):

В отличие от других ограничений, ограничение на просмотр числа голосов есть только на UI. Backend не запрещает подобные запросы, даже есть расширение, позволяющее просматривать это количество, работающее назависимо от репутации, и по поводу него был вопрос на метамете. Насколько я помню, там ответили, что это ok, а само ограничение нужно для того, чтобы не загромождать интерфейс новичка.

Comment: Ну не знаю... Мне сейчас с функцией просмотра голосов ничего интерфейс не загораживает. Уверен, что новички не "потеряются" в этом "мегасложном" UI.

Comment: @return, тем не менее, там был такой ответ. Можно поискать тот вопрос.